# How to best create this simple grid view on iPad?

Tags: ipad

I would like to recreate the interface below that allows the user to select a number by tapping a cell.  What do you think is the simplest way to implement this?  A UITableViewCell that has subviews added?  A UIWebView containing an HTML table? Custom UIButtons?

Thank you!

//Scott

[image]
<sub>(source: [spkant at home.comcast.net](http://home.comcast.net/~spkant/gridview.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass UIView, draw and do the touch detection yourself.

Comment: "Draw..."   But of course...the obvious has escaped me once again.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer should be updated to point to using UICollectionView that now comes started as part of iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) or [ATArrayView](http://github.com/apersaud/SoloComponents-iOS) for creating those types of grid elements.

**EDIT:** As of iOS6, you should look into [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) as it comes with the framework and it has more features.